# Do I need base href='/'?

Tags: angularjs, html

My understanding according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag) is that the default `base href` is `'/'`. [This scotch tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-angular-2-single-page-apps-with-the-component-router) says to include this base href:

```
<!-- ./index.html  -->
<base href="/">
```

For a basic app, is this strictly necessary, or will browsers assume that `'/'` is the `base href` for relative paths anyway?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> will browsers assume that '/' is the base href for relative paths anyway?

No, they will not.

The HTML spec [specifies how relative URLs are resolved](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/infrastructure.html#parsing-urls).  It's not too hard to work through the specification and definitions to find that when a relative URL is resolved against a document that does not have a base URL specified via a <base> element, the effective ("fallback") base URL is not guaranteed to be `/`.  There are a few alternatives, but in the usual case, the document's fallback base URL is taken as the document's own URL.  Typically, that's not `/`.

It's not so clear whether it's a good idea to specify `/` as every document's base URL.  It does mean that every relative URL will resolve the same way, regardless of the document in which it appears; that could be taken as a plus.  On the other hand, it differs from the default behavior for resolving relative URLs, which could be a source of bugs.  Certainly, if you choose to do it then you should do it consistently throughout the application.

Answer (score 1):

The base is the location the page is in. Every relative URL is relative to that `base`. Let us suppose you are at

```
http://a/b/c
```

If you have a link inside this page with this code:

```
<a href="../d">abc</a>
```

Then by clicking on the link, the `target` will be

```
http://a/d
```

So, your `base` is at

```
http://a/b
```

because `c` is inside that. Now that you understand what `base` is, take a look [here](http://www.htmldog.com/references/html/tags/base/). You will see that besides `href`, you can set `target` as well, specifying where links should open.